# Dance pair algorithm (Male may dance with one or more women )

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a problem:-
There are m men and m women. Male may dance with one or more women or may not dance with any. Find One to one dancing partner pairs such that:
1. male dance partner is paired with women of his choice
2. No male or female dancer is left alone

```
public class DancePair 
{ 

    public static int totalmatching(int input1,String[] input2)
    {
        //Write code here
        String[] words=new String[input1];
        String[] words2=new String[input1];
        int i,j;
        System.out.println(input1);

        for(i=0;i<input1;i++)
        {
            words=input2[i].split("\\#");
            for(j=1;j<words.length;j++)
            {
                for(k=i+1;k<input1;k++)
                {
                    words2=input2[k].split("\\#");
                    for(p=1;p<words2.length;p++)
                    {
                        if(words[j]==words2.[p])
                        {
                            p++;
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            words3=input2[k+1].split("\\#");

                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Input is like:- M1#W2#W4,M2#W1#W2,M3#W1#W3#W4,M4#W4#W5,M5#W4
OUTPUT should come for this i/p as 1
I have created this code but i am stucking in the loop and unable to proceed. Need help

Comment: I think you will have to read something about backtracking. Try entering the word into your favourite search engine for a start. Backtracking is a class of algorithms used for problems like the one you describe.

Comment: There may not always be a solution. Consider M1#W1,M2#W1,M3#W2#W3. With this input you will have to leave either M1 or M2 alone.

Comment: By the way, try to devise better variable names. In your code I had expected to read about dancers and choices; names like `input1`, `words`, `i` and `p` are probably meaningful to yourself and nobody else.

Comment: I couldn’t resist, I have written a solution. Since it is not very stackoverflow-ish to post a full solution when all you asked for is help with your own solution — I will post mine if you tell me you would like to have it.

Comment: Ole V.V. if in case M1 or M2 are alone then the output must be -1... Yeah i really need help give ur solution

Comment: Excuse my curiosity, or interest, if you will: Are you finding the answers useful? How are you proceding?

Comment: ur answer is too difficult for me to understand. I dont have much knowledge of backtracking

Comment: So I hope the graph algorithm answer is better. It was quite a difficult problem you had set out to solve, I don’t think any really easy answers can exist.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a variation [Maximum Matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_unweighted_bipartite_graphs). You need to find the maximum matching in this bipartite graph. The only difference is a man can dance with multiple women. So when you construct your graph, for each man you put multiple nodes with respect to its degree. Consider the following example:

```
M1: W1, W2
M2: W3
```

You have to put 2 nodes for `M1`:

```
M1: W1, W2
M1': W1, W2
M2: W3
```

Now you can run maximum matching on this graph, and it will give you the desired result.

Comment: With m men and m women and no dancer left alone, the requirements imply that each man is dancing with exactly one woman, so I don’t thnik you need two nodes for M1?

Comment: The question is very vague. I explained my understanding of the problem. But if the OP actually meant what you have said then there is no need for node repetition and a simple maximum matching would suffice.

Comment: I upvoted this asnwer for the theoretical foundation and its potential for better performance than the backtracking. With 5 men and 5 women, performance doesn’t matter, but with hundreds of dancers it might make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing that much about graph theory and algorithms, I developed my algorithm using backtracking. It’s a few hundred lines of code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class DancePair {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DancePair();
    }

    public DancePair() {
        totalMatching("M1#W2#W4,M2#W1#W2,M3#W1#W3#W4,M4#W4#W5,M5#W4");
    }

    List<Choice> choices = new ArrayList<>();

    /** solution */
    Choice[] pairs;

    private void totalMatching(String input) {
        // expect m men and m women
        int m = parseInput(input);
        // build m couples
        solve(m);
    }

    private int parseInput(String input) {
        List<Dancer> men = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, Dancer> women = new HashMap<>();
        choices.clear();
        String[] choiceInput = input.split(",");
        for (String choicesAsString : choiceInput) {
            String[] dancerNames = choicesAsString.split("#");
            if (dancerNames.length < 2) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("No chosen women: " + choicesAsString);
            }
            Dancer man = new Dancer(dancerNames[0]);
            men.add(man);
            for (int ix = 1; ix < dancerNames.length; ix++) {
                Dancer woman = findDancer(women, dancerNames[ix]);
                choices.add(new Choice(man, woman));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("" + men.size() + " men: " + men);
        System.out.println("" + women.size() + " women: " + women.values());
        if (men.size() != women.size()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error: not the same number of men and women");
        }
        return men.size();
    }

    private Dancer findDancer(Map<String, Dancer> dancers, String name) {
        Dancer result = dancers.get(name);
        if (result == null) {
            result = new Dancer(name);
            dancers.put(name, result);
        }
        return result;
    }

    /** @param m Number of pairs required for a solution */
    private void solve(int m) {
        pairs = new Choice[m];
        tryPair(0, 0);
    }

    /** try to fill pairs[pairsStart] and onward using choices from choices.get(choicesStart) and onward */
    private void tryPair(int pairsStart, int choicesStart) {
        if (pairsStart == pairs.length) { // array is full, we have reached a solution
            printSolution();
        } else if (choicesStart < choices.size()) { // still choices to try
            Choice ch = choices.get(choicesStart);
            // try with and without ch
            if (ch.isOpen()) {
                ch.pair();
                pairs[pairsStart] = ch;
                tryPair(pairsStart + 1, choicesStart + 1);
                ch.unpair();
            }
            tryPair(pairsStart, choicesStart + 1);
        }
    }

    private void printSolution() {
        System.out.println("Solution: " + Arrays.toString(pairs));
    }

}
```

The program prints:

```
5 men: [M1, M2, M3, M4, M5]
5 women: [W1, W2, W3, W4, W5]
Solution: [M1+W2, M2+W1, M3+W3, M4+W5, M5+W4]
```

You should still read a tutorial or two on backtracking in order to understand the code. I’m sure there’s room for performance optimization. The code uses a couple of auxiliary classes. Here’s `Choice` (could also be named `PossiblePariring`):

```
import java.util.Objects;

/** the fact that femaleDancer is included in maleDancer’s women of choice */
public class Choice {
    final Dancer maleDancer;
    final Dancer femaleDancer;
    public Choice(Dancer maleDancer, Dancer femaleDancer) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(maleDancer);
        Objects.requireNonNull(femaleDancer);
        this.maleDancer = maleDancer;
        this.femaleDancer = femaleDancer;
    }

    /** can this man and woman be paired? */
    boolean isOpen() {
        return ! maleDancer.isPaired() && ! femaleDancer.isPaired();
    }

    public void pair() {
        if (! isOpen()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Already paired? " + maleDancer.isPaired() + ' ' + femaleDancer.isPaired());
        }
        maleDancer.setPaired(true);
        femaleDancer.setPaired(true);
    }

    /** undo pair() */
    public void unpair() {
        if (! (maleDancer.isPaired() && femaleDancer.isPaired())) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Paired? " + maleDancer.isPaired() + ' ' + femaleDancer.isPaired());
        }
        maleDancer.setPaired(false);
        femaleDancer.setPaired(false);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + maleDancer + '+' + femaleDancer;
    }
}
```

And finally the quite simple `Dancer`:

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class Dancer {
    final String name;
    boolean paired = false;

    public Dancer(String name) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(name);
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isPaired() {
        return paired;
    }

    public void setPaired(boolean paired) {
        this.paired = paired;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about  *bipartite graphs* but I'm able to solve this using simple backtracking solution.

Below is the working C# solution (which anyone can easily modify for Java):
*(First convert  `M1#W2#W4,M2#W1#W2,M3#W1#W3#W4,M4#W4#W5,M5#W4` to 2d array of 0 and 1)*

```
public static bool countPairsBT(int[,] map, int[] occupiedCol, int curCol, int[] count, int N, int[,] solMap)
            {
                if (curCol == N)
                {
                    count[0]++; // inc count becuz it's a solution
                    printSol(solMap, N); // print this solution
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    return true;
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                {
                    if (map[curCol, j] == 1 && occupiedCol[j] == 0)
                    {
                        occupiedCol[j] = 1;
                        solMap[curCol, j] = 1;
                        countPairsBT(map, occupiedCol, curCol + 1, count, N, solMap);

                        occupiedCol[j] = 0; // BACKTRACK
                        solMap[curCol, j] = 0;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

            public static void printSol(int[,] map, int N)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(map[i,j]);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int[,] map =
                {
                    {1 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,1 },
                    {1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,0 },
                    {0 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,1 },
                    {0 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,1 },
                    {1 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 }
                };


            int[] count = new int[1];
            int N = map.GetLength(0); // get N for NxN 2d array
            int[] occupiedCol = new int[N];
            int[,] solMap = new int[N, N];
            countPairsBT(map, occupiedCol, 0, count, N, solMap);
            Console.WriteLine(count[0]); //print count
            Console.ReadKey();
            }
```

**Output:**

```
10000
00010
00100
01000
00001

00010
10000
00100
01000
00001

00010
00100
00001
01000
10000

00001
00010
00100
01000
10000

4
```