# How to approach for match counts?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

There are m men and m women in a dance group. Each man may either to 
dance with one or more than one women in a group or may not to dance 
with any women in the group. Find one to one dancing partner matches for
these group of men and women such that:

1. The male dance partner is paired with woman dancer of his choice.
2. No male or female dancer is left alone.

The output must return total number of matches possible . If the dance 
partner match is not possible then the output returned will be -1.

Take an Example :

M1 to M5 Men and W1 to W5 Women.

M1 want to dance with W2,W4
M2 want to dance with W1,W2
M3 want to dance with W1,W3,W4
M4 want to dance with W4,W5
M5 want to dance with W5

There is no preference order to dance with.

he only valid dance partner match in this situation is M1 
to W2, M2 to W1, M3 to W3, M4 to W5, M5 to W4. There is no other valid 
dance partner match. Hence, the output is 1.

Nearest I could think is, stable marriage but how to get counts ?

Comment: Try googling "counting perfect matchings in a bipartite graph".

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide the source of the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dance pair algorithm (Male may dance with one or more women )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39316227/dance-pair-algorithm-male-may-dance-with-one-or-more-women)